# How to change the background color of a ListView row?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, listview

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new mainEntities())
    {
        people = (from p in db.People select p).ToList();
    }
    foreach (Person p in People)
    {                
        listView.Items.Add(p);
    }            
}
```

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView" Foreground="Black">            
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gridView">
            <GridViewColumn Header="name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Spec" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Career}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I used an ADO.Net entity model to create the `Person` object model from my database, create a list of `Person` objects from the database and then add that list to a `ListView` to display to columns using bindings. I want to change the color of the `ListView` rows based on the value of `Career`. For instance set the row to red if `Career=='Nurse'`.

The problem I seem to have is that the `Person` object is not a `ListViewItem` so I can not set the `Background` Property.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your code. You have `foreach (Person in People)` but then `listView.Items.Add(r);`. What is `r`?

Comment: I can't see the code where you try to set the `Background` property. Could you add that too? Also please include full exception details if you encounter any.

Comment: Sorry r should be p, and it should be 'foreach (person p in people)' I've fixed it now

Comment: btw you didn't need that call to `Dispose`, it's done for you by the `using` construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a DataTrigger in your ListView. Add the DataTrigger will detect the binding value and change the ListViewItem Background.

Style the ListViewItem in xaml directly. See the following code sample:

```
  <ListView x:Name="listView" Foreground="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gridView">
                <GridViewColumn Header="name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Spec" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Career}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Career}"
                  Value="Nurse">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

[image]